# There is no ethic in OPs delete my user

Tags: support

It is obvious for me: answers are not representative of a community because censorship of operators. Delete my account.

Answer (score 5):

You weren't "censored by the operators." I assume you're referring to your [answer to this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/51370/9550). That answer was deleted because three ordinary users of the site voted to delete it. One of those users was me; I have enough reputation on the site to see who the other two were and I can confirm that they were not moderators.

Note that there are comments pointing out that people cannot understand your answer and also that the second comment below the question explains that unprovability in some axiom system and undecidability are two different things. Finally, most of your answer is actually not an answer at all but a rant about the way you feel you've been treated here.

Those are the reasons that I voted to delete the answer.  I assure you that this has nothing to do with the fact that we argued in the comments to one of your other answers but I understand if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry if you had a bad experience here.

However, we do not practice censorship, and this is not an ethical issue. We practice editorial control. There's a difference, and ignoring it does not help your case.

Having looked at your answers, I don't understand them, even though they are about a topic that I understand. Judging by other people's reactions, my impression is shared. Maybe you have a problem writing in English, or maybe you didn't understand the questions. Either way, posts that are incomprehensible are not useful to anyone, so we delete them. It doesn't help that the answer of yours that was deleted was a strange mixture of an attempt to answer the question and a rant about not being liked.

You're welcome to stay around, but please do try to write answers that people can understand. This is a question and answer site, not a speaker's corner.

Alternatively, if you wish your account to be deleted, use the [contact form](https://cs.stackexchange.com/contact) and select “I need to delete my user profile”.

Answer (score 1):

There is no censorship, as for moderators I am certain that they are not responsible for whatever happened.
I felt similar to you in a way, but still, this is community based, not moderators/operators.

And deletion is from settings and changing username to "delete my account" afaik.